# Valor por defecto en un select usando laravel y Mysql

Tags: html, select

como podria poner un valor por defecto como "Seleccione una opcion" en un select, estoy realizando un unos campos para realizar busquedas por filtros, en este caso una de las opciones sera la de busqueda por estados, estos los tengo en una tabla en mysql la cual la mando a llamar para que se muestren con la ayuda de un foreach, pero en caso que el usuario no quiera realizar la busqueda por este campo como le podria hacer para agregar en primera posicion una opcion y que sea la que se seleccione por default?

este es mi codigo

```
<div class="form-group linea">
        <label>Estado</label><br>
        <select id="select_estado" >
        
            @foreach($state as $s)
            
            <option value="{{$s->Id_Estado}}">{{$s->Nombre_Estado}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

un saludo y gracias de antemano

Comment: Dentro del Select y antes del foreach puedes declarar otro option con las características deseadas

Comment: gracias me fue de ayuda

Comment: No hay de que, pública tu mismo cómo quedó tu solución y así podemos votarla

Answer (score 1):

esta fue la solución

```
<div class="form-group linea">
        <label>Estado</label><br>
        <select id="select_estado" >
            <option value="selected">Seleccione una opcion</option>
            @foreach($state as $s)
            
            <option value="{{$s->Id_Estado}}">{{$s->Nombre_Estado}}</option>
            
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```